# $\mathbb{N}$ is not definable in a non-standard model

Tags: logic, nonstandard-models

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a non-standard model of arithmetic and consider the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\mathbb{N}$ is NOT a definable subset of $\mathcal{M}$.

My attempt so far is to note that **since $\mathcal{M}$ is a model in $Th(\mathbb{N})$ then every definable subset must have a least element**. Moreover, since definable sets are closed under complement if $\mathbb{N}$ is definable then $M\setminus\mathbb{N}$ should be too, but $M\setminus \mathbb{N}$ is a set of infinite numbers and so, it doesn't have a least element.

What I want to understand is why every definable subset in $Th(\mathbb{N})$ must have a least element?

Comment: For any $\phi$ with parameters, the sentence “for all values of the parameters, if there is an element satisfying $\phi$, then there is a least element satisfying $\phi$” holds in $\mathbb N$. Thus it holds in any nonstandard model. But I don’t see your reasoning for why $M-\Omega(M)$ has no least element. Surely “it is a set of infinite numbers” doesn’t literally suffice.

Comment: I am thinking $M\setminus \Omega(M)$ as the set of all the infinite numbers in $\mathcal{M}$ and since if $\beta$ is an infinite number then $\beta-1, \beta-2$ are also infinite numbers and so on, then as a set it doesn't have a least element. It has lower bounds which are any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ thou.

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea.

Comment: Also there is a different argument: if $\Omega(\mathcal{M})$ was definable, then the sentence defining it would define the whole universe in the standard model, and so would also be the whole universe in $\mathcal{M}$. This is the induction principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ be defined by some formula $\phi_X$. Then, since *every* subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a least element (it's well ordered) we have

$$\mathbb{N} \models \exists a . \phi_X(a) \land \forall x . (\phi_X(x) \to a \leq x)$$

This is a first order sentence saying that $a$ is a minimal element of $X^{(\mathbb{N})}$.

But now, we find $\exists a . \phi_X(a) \land \forall x . (\phi_X(x) \to a \leq x)$ is in $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$, and so any model of $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ must also satisfy it. In particuler, $\mathcal{M}$ models it, and so $X$ has a least element in $\mathcal{M}$.

This is an application of *transfer* in first order logic. If we know something about some model of $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$, and everything in sight is first order, then we can *transfer* that result to other models of $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ as well. So by *proving* the theorem for some special choice of model (in this case we chose $\mathbb{N}$, because it's well ordered), we actually get to claim the result for *all* models.

Indeed, we had a definable set $X$. Then we transferred our question about it $\mathbb{N}$, where the problem was easy to solve, then we transfered the result back to $\mathcal{M}$.

More generally, you can run this argument with *any* complete theory. You can transfer first order properties from one model to another. This is one of the big ways that model theory is used in "mainstream" mathematics.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I does! thanks so much

Comment: Happy to help ^_^ If it answered your question, you should mark it as "accepted" so that other users know where they should spend their time